# how to sum varchar values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am loading multiple text files into a database using the Load Data infile statement. There seems to be an issue when trying to load numeric values into a their respective numeric fields. I did some research and per [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html), all data loaded in is treated as text, so all the values are being input as null.

> LOAD DATA INFILE regards all input as strings, so you cannot use
>   numeric values for ENUM or SET columns the way you can with INSERT
>   statements. All ENUM and SET values must be specified as strings.

I tried casting the specific fields as numeric or decimal and I still get null values in the table.

I.E.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'blabla.txt' INTO TABLE example  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ignore 1 lines
(field1, field2, field3, @problemfield,)

set problemfield= cast((REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@problemfield,',',''),'(', '-'), ')','')) as DECIMAL(10,0));
```

*I am using the replaces because sometimes negatives are in parentheses in the data.*

There were similar questions on stackoverflow about casting when loading in and many responses(cant find the links now) suggest loading in as text, then transferring to new numeric field and deleting old field, is that an optimal solution ? How is this issue usually handled? Since I am sure this scenario must happen a lot (load all this text data and perform operations on them)

Comment: The quotation that you cite from the manual (about `ENUM` and `SET` columns) is irrelevant.  Just because the input is typed as a string should not stop MySQL correctly converting to a numeric type on insertion, especially since you are manipulating (and then manually casting) the string to make it valid.  Most likely there is some peculiarity in your file format that you are not handling.  Can you show a sample extract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your data into a staging table.  Manipulate as required.  Write to your real tables from your staging table.